# Is there a way to Expand All Nodes with breezejs?

Tags: angularjs, breeze

Is there to expand all child nodes on an entity using the breezejs query statement? Maybe even 2 deep?

Scenario is I'm doing a partial entity for the list page but on edit of a single entity I want to show all data, do I really have to .expand('every', 'single', 'child', 'node', 'field') ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify every *leg* but you get some economy by expressing *long legs*.

For example, you can write this three-legged `.expand("a.b.c.d, a.e, f.g.h")` and you'll get the related a,b,c,d,e,f,g and h entities.

If you want to get clever, you can generate the expand clauses from the metadata. I think I'd just write the expand myself.